# Issues when using unique package name for Google Play and Samsung Galaxy store

Tags: android, firebase, facebook, google-play, galaxy

We have an existing Android app in the Google Play Store, and we are looking at publishing the same app to the Samsung Galaxy Store. We are unsure whether it would be better to use the same package name or a different package name for the Samsung Galaxy Store.

The Samsung [docs](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-games/recommendations-to-bring-your-game.html) say it is "recommended" to use a unique / different package name. Doing so also prevents [cross-store issues](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.3/Documentation/Manual/UnityIAPCrossStoreInstallationIssues.html) with in-app purchases.

The thing is, we are using Firebase in our app. Firebase relies on the package name, and changing it will cause Firebase to stop working. Is it possible to have 2 android apps (with different package names) use the same Firebase project? If so, will everything still work as normal for both apps (Remote Config, Messaging / Push Notifications, etc)?

We also have other integrations that rely on the package name (such as the Facebook SDK). Unless it's possible to have 2 Android package names for a Facebook app, it seems there is no easy way for us to use two different package names for the Play Store and the Galaxy Store.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have 2 android apps (with different package names) use the same Firebase project? If so, will everything still work as normal for both apps (Remote Config, Messaging / Push Notifications, etc)?

**YES**

> Is it possible to have 2 Android package names for a Facebook app

**NO**

My Recommendation is to use the same package name with two different versions or variants (let the user know that this is a Samsung version or Google Play and in the market description and privacy policy mention that these are different versions)